# Calculating a weighted correlation using different vector weights for each variable in R

Tags: r, statistics, correlation, weighted

I would like to calculate a weighted correlation between two variables having different weights.

Some example data:

```
DF = data.frame(
  x = c(-0.3, 0.3, -0.18, 0.02, 0.07, 0.11, 0.20, 0.8, 0.3, -0.4),
  x_weight = c(50, 40, 70, 5, 15, 30, 32, 13, 9, 19),
  y = c(-0.6, 0.25, 0.1, 0.3, 0.3, -0.05, -0.5, 1, 0.05, -0.6),
  y_weight = c(70, 8, 10, 39, 9, 49, 90, 77, 23, 75)
)
DF
```

I read about cov.wt in the stats package, but it only allows input for one vector of weights. Essentially I'm looking for similar inputs as wtd.t.test, but to calculate a correlation instead.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate the weighted correlation between two variables using the following formula `Formulas are based on the definition of weighted covariance and correlation`.

First, calculate the weighted means for the two variables using the weights:

```
mu_x = sum(DF$x * DF$x_weight) / sum(DF$x_weight)
mu_y = sum(DF$y * DF$y_weight) / sum(DF$y_weight)
```

Next, calculate the weighted covariance between the two variables:

```
cov_xy = sum((DF$x - mu_x) * (DF$y - mu_y) * DF$x_weight * DF$y_weight) / sum(DF$x_weight * DF$y_weight)
```

Finally, calculate the weighted correlation between the two variables:

```
cor_xy = cov_xy / (sqrt(sum((DF$x - mu_x)^2 * DF$x_weight) / sum(DF$x_weight)) * sqrt(sum((DF$y - mu_y)^2 * DF$y_weight) / sum(DF$y_weight)))
```

Comment: Thank you many times! Do you have any suggestions on how to bootstrap the correlation? I'm trying, but unsuccessful..