# How to perform bootstrap on weighted correlation in R?

Tags: r, correlation, resampling, weighted

I'm trying to bootstrap a weighted correlation in R, with the different data streams having separate weights.

Some example data:

```
DF = data.frame(
  x = c(-0.3, 0.3, -0.18, 0.02, 0.07, 0.11, 0.20, 0.8, 0.3, -0.4),
  x_weight = c(50, 40, 70, 5, 15, 30, 32, 13, 9, 19),
  y = c(-0.6, 0.25, 0.1, 0.3, 0.3, -0.05, -0.5, 1, 0.05, -0.6),
  y_weight = c(70, 8, 10, 39, 9, 49, 90, 77, 23, 75)
)
DF
```

Because x and y have differents weightings, I can't use cov.wt, but I need to self-define the formulas (thanks to the answer on this post: [Calculating a weighted correlation using different vector weights for each variable in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75371500/calculating-a-weighted-correlation-using-different-vector-weights-for-each-varia))

First calculate the weighted covariance

```
library(Hmisc)
cov = 
    sum(((DF$x - wtd.mean(x=DF$x, w=DF$x_weight)) * DF$x_weight) * ((DF$y - wtd.mean(x=DF$y, w=DF$y_weight)) * DF$y_weight))  / 
    sum(DF$x_weight * DF$y_weight)
```

Then calculate the weighted correlation

```
cor = cov / (sqrt(sum((DF$x - wtd.mean(x=DF$x, w=DF$x_weight))^2 * DF$x_weight) / sum(DF$x_weight)) *  
                 sqrt(sum((DF$y - wtd.mean(x=DF$y, w=DF$x_weight))^2 * DF$y_weight) / sum(DF$y_weight)))
```

This works, but I would like to bootstrap the weighted correlation, at which I'm unsuccessful.

This is my attempt:

```
weightedcorrelation = function(DF){
  cov = sum(((DF$x - wtd.mean(x=DF$x, w=DF$x_weight)) * DF$x_weight) * ((DF$y - wtd.mean(x=DF$y, w=DF$y_weight)) * DF$y_weight))  / sum(DF$x_weight * DF$y_weight)
  cor = cov / (sqrt(sum((DF$x - wtd.mean(x=DF$x, w=DF$x_weight))^2 * DF$x_weight) / sum(DF$x_weight)) * sqrt(sum((DF$y - wtd.mean(x=DF$y, w=DF$x_weight))^2 * DF$y_weight) / sum(DF$y_weight)))
  return(cor)
}
weightedcorrelation(DF)

library(boot)
boot(data = DF[, , drop=F], 
     statistic = weightedcorrelation, 
     R = 1000)
```

I'm getting an error on the statistic argument.
Also, boot has the option of including a weights arguments, which I'm not using right now.

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust your `weightedcorrelation` function, so that it takes two arguments (required if you are doing `sim="ordinary"` (which is what you **are** doing, given your current call to `boot()`); the two arguments are `d` (the data) and (for example) `i` (the indices):

```
weightedcorrelation = function(d,i){
  DF = d[i,]
  cov = sum(((DF$x - wtd.mean(x=DF$x, w=DF$x_weight)) * DF$x_weight) * ((DF$y - wtd.mean(x=DF$y, w=DF$y_weight)) * DF$y_weight))  / sum(DF$x_weight * DF$y_weight)
  cor = cov / (sqrt(sum((DF$x - wtd.mean(x=DF$x, w=DF$x_weight))^2 * DF$x_weight) / sum(DF$x_weight)) * sqrt(sum((DF$y - wtd.mean(x=DF$y, w=DF$x_weight))^2 * DF$y_weight) / sum(DF$y_weight)))
  return(cor)
}
```

Comment: Thank you! 
Your code seems to be working, but I don't understand how? 
Is the i keeping the original x and x_weight (and y and y_weight) combinations together? For example, does x = -0.3 still have a weight of 50 in the bootstrap?